# UITap gesture only works on one view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code in a view controller:

```
@interface QuizController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *questionText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *one;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *two;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *three;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *four;

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* possAnswers;
@end

@implementation QuizController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self.manager setupGame];
   self.possAnswers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", nil];

}

//This listens for a tap on any of the TextViews and sets the background to Blue 

- (IBAction)fourTapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"There's been a tap!");
    [self blankBoxes];

    if( [sender isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]] )
    {

        UITapGestureRecognizer* tgr = (UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender;
        UIView* view = tgr.view;
        if( [view isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]){
            UITextView* tv = (UITextView*)view;
            NSLog([tv text]);
            [tv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        }

    }

}

-(void)blankBoxes
{
  [_one setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
  [_two setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
  [_three setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
  [_four setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

However, the only `UITextView` that gets highlighted is `_one`, no matter which view is tapped. I don't understand why this is. I'd be really grateful if anyone could point this out to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gesture recognizers attach to one and only one view. That's by design. If you want a single gesture recognizer that lets you recognize taps on multiple views, you have to attach it to a common, enclosing superview, then look at the tap coordinates and figure out which view was tapped.

Normally you just create a different gesture recognizer for each view that needs to responds to taps.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `UIGestureRecognizer` to a `UIView` that contains your subviews. After that use `CGRectContainsPoint()` to check if the tap location is in one of the subviews, then continue from there.

```
CGPoint *touchLocation = [gesture locationInView:self];

for(UIView *view in self.subviews){

     if(CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, touchLocation))
        //Your code here


}
```